# Regex: Get number of occurrences to be matched from the number of occurrences matched by previous group

Tags: java, regex

I've the following regex

```
\d{2,4}\-\d{6,8}
```

But is it possible to match only 6 digits after the hyphen when 4 digits are matched before hyphen.i.e, I want to match only the following cases:

```
XX-XXXXXXXX
XXX-XXXXXXX
XXXX-XXXXXX
```

where X is a digit.

Comment: Since you only have three cases, use alternation with `|`.

Comment: [`^(?:\d{2}-\d{8}|\d{3}-\d{7}|\d{4}-\d{6})$`](https://regex101.com/r/sRWnpQ/1). However, it does not scale much.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me! You ask is it possible to match only 6 digits after the hyphen when 4 digits are matched before hyphen.i.e,  but in the example your requirement is different!

Comment: See my new comment.

Comment: So it looks like you want to match a total of 10 digits, right? You can do this by writing a regex for each case and using `|`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, what if there are more than three cases? Using OR will not be the best solution in this case.

Comment: Then you should describe your requirements more clearly so that we can provide a more suitable answer.

Comment: Using OR is fine for the question I posted. I wanted to know if there is any other solution that could be applied for more than three cases. Anyhow, thanks for the solution, @Code-Apprentice :)

Comment: @PurvajaSuresh When posting a question, you should show what you have tried already. Then explain why the attempt doesn't do what you want. This will avoid wasting a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is validate the total length in addition to the separate parts' lengths :

```
^(?=[\d-]{11}$)\d{2,4}-\d{6,8}$
```

However in this case it really seems more simple to list the 3 alternatives, as commented by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/) :

```
^(?:\d{2}-\d{8}|\d{3}-\d{7}|\d{4}-\d{6})$
```

Comment: The point here is that the consuming part of the first pattern won't match more than 1 hyphen, the `(?=[\d-]{11}$)` lookahead will just count 11 digits or hyphens, but its result will be "corrected" later by the consuming pattern.